# SQL INNER JOIN CASE SPECIFIC

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Below is my database table structure

`ApplicationModule` - Id, Key, Name

`ApplicationFeature` - Id, ModuleId, Key, Name

Each feature is mapped with Module. Also I need to assign only some features to Tenant.

`TenantXFeature` - TenantId, FeatureId

Also when I create a role, I map few features picked from Tenant Specific(TenantXFeature)

`RoleXFeature` - RoleId, FeatureId

Now I need a query to load all the tenant specific features along with the selection(Y/N), if RoleXFeature have entry for the feature.

```
SELECT AM.[Key] AS ModuleKey
      ,AM.Name AS ModuleName
      ,AF.[Key] AS FeatureKey
      ,AF.Name FeatureName
      ,RF.FeatureId
      ,CASE WHEN RF.FeatureId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Selected
  FROM TenantXFeature TF
  INNER JOIN ApplicationFeature AF
    ON TF.FeatureId = AF.Id
  INNER JOIN ApplicationModule AM
    ON AF.ModuleId = AM.Id 
  LEFT JOIN RoleXFeature RF
    ON RF.FeatureId = AF.Id AND RF.RoleIid = 1
  WHERE TF.TenantId = 1
```

Here `RF.FeatureId` always shows NULL even If I have a mapping in RoleXFeature.

Please suggest/help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Do you have a table to map tenants to roles?

Comment: @MarkBannister, I dont have a seperate Mapping table, but in ApplicationRole table we have a column `TenantId` indicates role is specific to Tenant. `NULL` value in that column specifies it is common to all Tenants.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are no features related at the same time to a role with id=1 and to tenant with id=1

Features not related to role id=1 or to tenant id=1:

```
SELECT *
FROM ApplicationFeature f
WHERE (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TenantXFeature WHERE FeatureId = f.Id AND TenantId=1)
OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM RoleXFeature WHERE FeatureId = f.Id AND RoleId=1))
```

Features related both to role id=1 and tenant id=1:

```
SELECT *
FROM ApplicationFeature f
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TenantXFeature WHERE FeatureId = f.Id AND TenantId=1)
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM RoleXFeature WHERE FeatureId = f.Id AND RoleId=1)
```

[Playground on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f2ef/2)

Comment: As a cross-check on this answer, change the original query to use an INNER JOIN.  If there are no rows in RoleXFeature which map to a TenantId of 1 and RoleId of 1 the query will return no rows.

Comment: I checked your fiddle. I removed one data and assuming Tenant got mapped with only 3 Features. Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac83a/1 . All i need is now i should select all these 3 features along with the column selected, which indicateds 1 or 0 based on role. In this case I should get Feature1 with `1` and others with `0`